# Apache and Passenger HelperAgent

Tags: apache, passenger

I'm using latest apache/passenger setup. Out of know where I started getting a strange error in passenger. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
[ 2014-07-08 08:12:30.0478 7138/7f19ef53c740 apache2/Hooks.cpp:732 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the helper agent at /tmp/passenger.1.0.1170/generation-0/request
      Backtrace:
         in 'Passenger::FileDescriptor Hooks::connectToHelperAgent()' (Hooks.cpp:291)
         in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:546)
```

Comment: Which version of Passenger is this?

Answer (score 0):

Restart apache it should help you resolve this issue.

I got similar problem and ran this which worked for me

sudo service httpd status

sudo service httpd restart